# mat-toolbar not displayed with mat-grid-list

Tags: angular, angular-material, toolbar

I have a component containing a toolbar and a grid list like this:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary"></mat-toolbar>
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="5:1">
   ...
</mat-grid-list>
```

My problem is that the grid list take the place of the toolbar, so my toolbar is not well displayed.
this is my toolbar css:

```
mat-toolbar {
position: fixed;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
}
```

Could someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `position: fixed`. You have to change it or remove it completely.

To order the items in your toolbar check out [this link](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs).

Based on your code, you probably just have to add `fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center"` to the parent of the elements

Comment: ok for this, but if I have a component that contains a toolbar, and other component containing a toolbar, only the toolbar of the first component is displayed. I posted a question about this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566459/angular-multiple-components-rendering-view-problem)

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz with your code? it is easier to help you out

Comment: I created it, [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmrqjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar-two%2Ftoolbar-two.component.css)