# Angular multiple components rendering view problem

Tags: angular, components, toolbar

I have 2 components: the first one contains a toolbar, and the second one an other toolbar elements.
I call my 2 components inside my app.component.html like this:

```
<first-component></first-component>
<second-component></second-component>
```

My problem is that the only the toolbar contained within the first component is displayed.
Otherwise If I put the two toolbar directly in the app.component.html I don't get the problem.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example?

Comment: A simple [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eau2k7) with two components works fine. Can you provide some code ?

Comment: if you use the angular material <mat-toolbar> instead of <p> it will not works.

Comment: @Tzimpo with angular material toolbar it doesn't work

Comment: Did you espect the code from developer tools?maybe is a css problem and comp1 is over comp2!If you create a stackblitz exampe with mat-toolbar we can check it

Comment: @Tzimpo yes I am creating it, 2 min

Comment: I added mat-toolbar and working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eau2k7

Comment: @Tzimpo this the exemple [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmrqjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar-one%2Ftoolbar-one.component.html), the problem came from css when I am trying to make the first toolbar fix, how could I resolve this ?

Comment: @Tzimpo the problem is the position:fixed within css files. I want to have two fixed toolbar. How could I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the css on your first component to

```
mat-toolbar {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* For macOS/iOS Safari */
  top: 0; /* Sets the sticky toolbar to be on top */
  z-index: 1000; 
}
```

Comment: but I want the two toolbars to be fixed

Comment: yes but this doesn't make them fixed, If I scroll down they will disappear

Comment: you can see the example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmrqjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar-two%2Ftoolbar-two.component.css)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly you want a double sticky toolbar.

For this you don't have to define two components.

Angular Material already provides a solution. Check this [link](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/examples)

I also created a stackblitz that contains your two toolbars:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdjgps?file=src/app/toolbar-multirow-example.css

If you truly need two components then here is the solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zlm512?file=src/app/toolbar-one/toolbar-one.component.css

Comment: Yes, but for my project I should have two components

Comment: i edited my initial answer :) hope this solves your problem